# How can i add a condition string to an sql query in an var type

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, .net-3.5

Im working on an source code with an sql query in a VAR type like

```
var query = select ... from ... where ... ;
```

is it possible to add an dynamic "where clause" like

```
string condition = "where x.x > x.y"; 

e.g. var query = select ... from ... + condition;
```

Iam sorry for my bad english

Comment: Quellcode? What is that?

Comment: I'm sorry, but your code does not make sense. Is it C# strings? Then you should have quotes around them. Is it LINQ2SQL, then you should have code like [var query = from x in foo select x].

Answer (score 0):

You are not clearly stating how your query looks like. Is it a result of a LINQ operation or simply a String?

The keyword var is only usable for design time. The compiler will substitute it with the correct datatype.

If you SQL query is a string, like

```
var query = "Select ... from ... where ..";
```

then

```
string condition = "where x.x > x.y";
query += condition;
```

is valid because both variables are strings. You can't combine a non string type with a string the way your code suggests.

I do now assume that you are using a LINQ syntax. It is possible to add such conditions to a linq query per code, I think the keywords linq query builder, expression tree and predicate should get you started.

I'd strongly suggest that you stop using the var keyword without exactly knowing what it does and where to use it.

Comment: Your suggestion to avoid the var keyword is very subjective.  Some people rather enjoy type inference. :)

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic Linq exists specifically to solve late-bound scenarios for LINQ:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Allows constructs such as:

```
NorthwindDataContext northwind = new NorthwindDataContext();

var query = northwind.Products
                        .Where("CategoryID = 3 AND UnitPrice > 3")
                        .OrderBy("SupplierID");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not call `ToList()` and your final mapping to the DTO type, you can add Where clauses as you go, and build the results at the end:

```
var query = from u in DataContext.Users
where u.Division == strUserDiv 
&& u.Age > 18
&& u.Height > strHeightinFeet
select u;

if (useAge)
query = query.Where(u => u.Age > age);

if (useHeight)
query = query.Where(u => u.Height > strHeightinFeet);

// Build the results at the end
var results = query.Select(u => new DTO_UserMaster
{
Prop1 = u.Name,
}).ToList();
```

This will still only result in a single call to the database, which will be effectively just as efficient as writing the query in one pass.

I saw this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10884651/linq-adding-conditions-to-the-where-clause-conditionally) by [Reed Copsey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10884651/linq-adding-conditions-to-the-where-clause-conditionally#:%7E:text=at%2016%3A31-,Reed%20Copsey,-542k76)