# Linq: adding conditions to the where clause conditionally

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I have a query like this

```
(from u in DataContext.Users
       where u.Division == strUserDiv 
       && u.Age > 18
       && u.Height > strHeightinFeet  
       select new DTO_UserMaster
       {
         Prop1 = u.Name,
       }).ToList();
```

I want to add the various conditions like age, height based on whether those conditions were provided to the method running this query. All conditions will include user Division. If age was supplied I want to add that to the query. Similarly, if height was provided I want to add that as well.

If this were to be done using sql queries I would have used string builder to have them appended to the main strSQL query. But here in Linq I can only think of using an IF condition where I will write the same query thrice, with each IF block having an additional condition. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 251, accepted):

If you do not call `ToList()` and your final mapping to the DTO type, you can add `Where` clauses as you go, and build the results at the end:

```
var query = from u in DataContext.Users
   where u.Division == strUserDiv 
   && u.Age > 18
   && u.Height > strHeightinFeet
   select u;

if (useAge)
   query = query.Where(u => u.Age > age);

if (useHeight)
   query = query.Where(u => u.Height > strHeightinFeet);

// Build the results at the end
var results = query.Select(u => new DTO_UserMaster
   {
     Prop1 = u.Name,
   }).ToList();
```

This will still only result in a single call to the database, which will be effectively just as efficient as writing the query in one pass.

Comment: Do I need to put all the where conditions in the "var query = .." statement?

Comment: The subsequent Where conditions are aggregated as OR or as AND?

Comment: @vi100 they'll be additional filters, so AND

Comment: Thank goodness for simplicity! I am so sick of seeing 20+ line Linq queries when the above is so much more readable

Comment: Why i am getting this error `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String get_Item(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`

Comment: @Rhyous If you want OR statements then you can just include them in the WHERE query directly. `query = query.Where(u => u.Age > age || u.Height > strHeightinFeet);`

Comment: @nse, I am pretty sure at the time I had one where statement per loop. So each call to Where() results in AND not OR. I believe I ended up solving this with LinqKit.

Comment: Only downside to this approach, is that you will need multiple local `var`s if you have two or more joins in your linq query where you need to apply the where conditionally on one of the join tables. Example: `from parent in parents from child in parent.children where conditionally from grandchild in child.children`

Comment: @ReedCopsey I doubt it will work when you have some join tables on your query, any solution for this case ?

Comment: @ReedCopsey How can we make OR conditions ?

Comment: What happens if you're NOT mapping to a DTO? If I remember correctly when I tried this there was major performance loss.

Comment: why does Raw SQL using Dapper feel like a better idea?

Answer (score 34):

I usually use method chaining but have the same problem. And here is extension I use

```
public static IQueryable<T> ConditionalWhere<T>(
        this IQueryable<T> source, 
        Func<bool> condition,
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        if (condition())
        {
            return source.Where(predicate);
        }

        return source;
    }
```

It helps to avoid chain breaks. Also the same `ConditionalOrderBy` and `ConditionalOrderByDescending` are helpful.

Comment: Helpful, but would you please add an example of what it would look like in use.

Comment: It should be like:
var fruits = await db.Fruits
    .ConditionalWhere(() => color != null, f=> f.Color == color)
    .ConditionalWhere(() => ripe != null, f => f.Ripe == ripe)
    .ToListAsync();

Comment: Works great! Thanks! I also made an overload for *condition* as a simple boolean value instead of a function, to make it more intuitive where a delegate would add unnecessary complexity. I use this extension method pretty frequently now and appreciate your solution very much.

Answer (score 25):

one option.

```
bool? age = null

(from u in DataContext.Users
           where u.Division == strUserDiv 
           && (age == null || (age != null && u.Age > age.Value))
           && u.Height > strHeightinFeet  
           select new DTO_UserMaster
           {
             Prop1 = u.Name,
           }).ToList();
```

or you could switch to the method syntax for linq and use if conditions to attach expressions to the where clause.

Answer (score 10):

Simply I am using it in my where clause as

```
    public IList<ent_para> getList(ent_para para){
     db.table1.Where(w=>(para.abc!=""?w.para==para.abc:true==true) && (para.xyz!=""?w.xyz==para.xyz:true==true)).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Based on certain condtion add the where condition
...

```
from u in DataContext.Users
where u.Division == strUserDiv 
&& u.Age != null ? u.Age > 18 : 1== 1
&& u.Height != null ? u.Height > 18 : 1== 1
&& u.Height != null ? u.Height > 18 : 1== 1
 select new DTO_UserMaster
       {
         Prop1 = u.Name,
       }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is my code to do a similar thing.  This is a method on my WCF SOAP Web Service api.

```
    public FruitListResponse GetFruits(string color, bool? ripe)
    {
        try
        {
            FruitContext db = new FruitContext();
            var query = db.Fruits.Select(f => f);
            if (color != null)
            {
                query = query.Where(f => f.Color == color);
            }
            if (ripe != null)
            {
                query = query.Where(f => f.Ripe == ripe);
            }
            return new FruitListResponse
            {
                Result = query.Select(f => new Fruit { Id = f.FruitId, Name = f.Name }).ToList()
            };
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return new FruitListResponse { ErrorMessage = e.Message };
        }
    }
```

The base query is `Select(f => f)` which means basically EVERYTHING, and the `Where` clauses are optionally attached to it.  The final `Select` is optional. I use to convert the database rows objects into result "Fruit" objects.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to the above accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10884757/3540340), 
if you are doing a dynamic search on a join, consider to return a new object with both tables (t1,t2) in the initial linq query so you can access them individually to do the conditional search.

```
var query = from t1 in _context.Table1
            join t2 in _context.Table2 on t1.Table1Id equals t2.Table1IdId
            select new { t1, t2 };

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchProperty1))
        {
            query = query.Where(collection => collection.t1.TableColumn == searchProperty1);
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchProperty2))
        {
            query = query.Where(collection => collection.t2.TableColumn == searchProperty2);
        }
        ....etc.
```

I got the answer i was looking for [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/deveshomar/dynamic-linq-library-in-C-Sharp/) in regards to joining two tables and querying specific columns on either of the tables

Answer (score 1):

I just came across this looking for something else, but thought I'd throw in lambda version.

First, I'd create a class like this to pass parameters into a data layer:

```
   public class SearchParameters() {
       public int? Age {get; set;}
       public string Division {get;set;}
       etc
    }
```

Then, in my data layer, something like this:

```
public IQueryable<User> SearchUsers(SearchParameters params) 
{
    var query = Context.Users;
    if (params.Age.HasValue)
    {
         query = query.Where(u => u.Age == params.Age.Value);
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(params.Division)
    {
        query = query.Where(u => u.Division == params.Division);
    }
    etc
    return query;
}
```

Where you materialize the query is up to you.  Might have a layer between the app and data which converts db-specific representations to db-agnostic (maybe you query multiple data sources).  That layer might get multiple types of queryables from these sources and map them to a common POCO representation, for example.

Comment: Oops, I didn't see John Henckel's answer.  Same idea.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming following parameter,

```
Int? Age = 18;
```

Simply using `&&` and `||` conditional operators we can have another version.

```
(from u in DataContext.Users
where u.Division == strUserDiv 
    && (Age == null || u.Age > Age)
    && (Param1 == null || u.param1 == Param1)
    && u.Height > strHeightinFeet
select new DTO_UserMaster
{
    Prop1 = u.Name,
}).ToList();
```

Like Param1 you can add any number of parameters for search condition.