# Pervasive Exclude paramters when 'NULL' in Ad-Hoc Query

Tags: pervasive

I am passing ad-hoc query from a `.NET` app to Pervasive v11 PSQL, I believe I cant declare variables outside of a stored procedure and view. Since I don't have the option to create stored procedure and view, how can I exclude parameters from where clause when `NULL`. If i dont pass a single parameter then i don't execute the query from .net.

The parameters I take are

> FirstName, LastName, DOB, Address, PersonID, OLnumber, PartSerialNumber

If any of the paramters are passed as `NULL`, I'd like the query to omit that specific `OR` clause.

```
Select FirstName,LastName,CaseNumer,DOB,Address from 
MasterTable mv LEFT JOIN  
AdditionalTable at ON  mv.PersonID = at.PersonID
LEFT JOIN Parts p ON mv.PersonID = p.PersonID
WHERE mv.OLNumber = '{ONumber}' OR at.OLNumber= '{ONumer}' 
OR (CONCAT(rtrim(mv.FirstName), rtrim(mv.LastName)) = replace(ltrim('{Name}'), ' ', ''))
OR (CONCAT(rtrim(at.FirstName), rtrim(at.LastName)) = replace(ltrim('{Name}'), ' ', ''))
OR p.PartSerialNumber = '{PartSerialNumber}'
OR mv.PersonID = '{PersonID}' OR at.PersonID = '{PersonID}'
OR mv.Address = '{Address}' or at.PersonID = '{PersonID}'
OR mv.DOB = '{DOB}' or at.DOB = '{DOB}'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linq: adding conditions to the where clause conditionally](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10884651/linq-adding-conditions-to-the-where-clause-conditionally)

Comment: no, im not using linq.

Comment: how are you building the query?

Comment: I think this should be tagged [`pervasive`](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pervasive/info), not [`plsql`](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/plsql/info).