# Cannot compare elements of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.String, mscorlib]]'. Only primitive types, enumeration

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

This is my EF query.

> Throw Ex: Cannot compare elements of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'. Only primitive types, enumeration

All parameters is full.

```
    public List<User> GetLawyersData(List<Guid> IdList, List<string> selectedCountries, List<string> selectedCities, List<string> selectedDistricts, List<string> selectedOccupations, List<string> selectedProfessions)
    {

        var result = (from u in _userDbContext
                      join ui in _userInformationDbContext
                      on u.Id equals ui.UserID
                      join d in _districtDbContext
                      on ui.DistrictId equals d.Id
                      join c in _cityDbContext
                      on d.CityID equals c.Id
                      join co in _countryDbContext
                      on c.CountryID equals co.Id
                      join uo in _userOccupationInformationDbContext
                      on u.Id equals uo.UserID
                      join oc in _occupationDbContext
                      on uo.OccupationID equals oc.Id
                      join up in _userProfessionDbContext
                      on u.Id equals up.UserID
                      join pr in _professionDbContext
                      on up.ProfessionID equals pr.Id
                      where IdList.Contains(u.Id) &&
                      (selectedCountries != null && selectedCountries.Count > 0 ? selectedCountries.Contains(co.AutoId.ToString()) : true) && (selectedCities != null && selectedCities.Count > 0 ? selectedCities.Contains(c.AutoId.ToString()) : true)
                      && (selectedDistricts != null && selectedDistricts.Count > 0 ?  selectedDistricts.Contains(d.AutoId.ToString()) : true)
                      && (selectedOccupations != null && selectedOccupations.Count > 0 ? selectedOccupations.Contains(oc.AutoId.ToString()) : true)
                      && (selectedProfessions != null && selectedProfessions.Count > 0 ? selectedProfessions.Contains(pr.AutoId.ToString()) : true)
                      select u).ToList();

        return result;
```

What can I do?

Comment: Comment out the parts of the `where` clause, one at a time. When the exception stops, the last thing you commented out was the cause. What was the cause?

Comment: Needs a lot more details. Like, what are these `_xyzContext` variables? Which EF version? (There are tags for that). Why do you join so massively instead of using navigation properties?

Comment: @GertArnold            


        private DbSet<PieceAuthor> _piceAuthorDbContext;
        private DbSet<City> _cityDbContext;
        private DbSet<Country> _countryDbContext;
        private DbSet<District> _districtDbContext;
        private DbSet<UserProfession> _userProfessionDbContext;
        private DbSet<Profession> _professionDbContext;

Comment: @GertArnold
these are inside constructor method 
       _piceAuthorDbContext = _context.Set<PieceAuthor>();
            _cityDbContext = _context.Set<City>();
            _countryDbContext = _context.Set<Country>();
            _districtDbContext = _context.Set<District>();
            _userProfessionDbContext = _context.Set<UserProfession>();
            _professionDbContext = _context.Set<Profession>();

Comment: @GertArnold 
EF 6.0 version

Comment: Add the checks to the query conditionally. Like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10884757/861716.

Comment: @YılmazKaraağaç How did you go with my suggestion? Which part was causing the issue?

Answer (score -1):

I think, the problem is that using ToString() function in linq query. You cannot use toString() on a field until been deserialized. So, rather than trying to call ToString() in the query, simply do it on the results afterwards or compare exact datatype values.

There is no notion of ToString() operation in database which is why you are getting error.

Comment: No, EF supports `ToString` in query expressions.

Comment: @GertArnold Its depend on EF version. the ToString() is supported properly going forward with EF 6.1 and above questioner using EF 6.0.