# how to add to linq query expression if a condition is met dynamically

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, expression, expression-trees

I have an expression tree built like this

```
Expression<Func<User, bool>> match = o =>
o.Name == viewModel.Name
&& orders.Contains(o.User.Company.CompanyId.ToString())
&& o.dept == viewModel.dept
```

I only want to include the line

```
o.dept == viewModel.dept
```

when viewModel.dept is 1, 2 or 3 and not include this condition in the expression tree, if it’s any other value.

This code is in a function that gets a viewModel as parameter and the values in the viewModel are used to query the EF model User.

Currently I have 2 separate expression trees to meet this scenario. Is there any better solution?

Thank you

Comment: Separate expressions, i.e. separate `Where()` calls is _the_ way to do it. Messing with the expression tree would be a lot more complicated and wouldn’t really give you a benefit.

Comment: Maybe : [Linq: adding conditions to the where clause conditionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10884651/linq-adding-conditions-to-the-where-clause-conditionally)

Comment: `(viewModel.dept == 1 || viewModel.dept == 2 || viewModel.dept == 3) && o.dept == viewModel.dept ` does not work?

Comment: @taquion, apologies it didn't work and I am still using 2 different expressions..

Comment: @poke, can you point us to some example for it.. in the end, I need to return expression of type Expression<Func<User, bool>>.. cheers

Comment: @Pravi The question linked by Servy does show some examples. Basically, just store the result from calling `Where()`, and then conditionally call `Where()` on that result again.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got a graceful solution using LINQKit (https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) and its PredicateBuilder
This is what I did.

```
var match = PredicateBuilder.New<User>(true);
match = match.And(o => o.Name == viewModel.Name);
match = match.And(o =>orders.Contains(o.User.Company.CompanyId.ToString()));
if(viewModel.dept==1 || viewModel.dept == 2 || viewModel.dept==3)
{
    match = match.And(o=>o.dept == viewModel.dept);
}

return match;
```

Comment: No need to use the predicate builder to AND the first two conditions together.  Just add them in a single expression.

Comment: @servy, correct, its a simple condition here, but, if the condition is complex than, its better to follow this approach..

Comment: It doesn't matter how simpler or complex the condition is.  All that really matters is whether you are composing them dynamically or not, and you're not.