# LINQ to SQL with if statement

Tags: c#, linq

I have a :

```
            var query = db.vw_web_GetAccounts; //a sql view
            if (some condition)
            {
                query.Where(...);
            }
            else
            {
                query.Where(...);
            }
            query.Select(a =>  new AccountVM
            {
                Name = a.Name,
                ....
            });

            return query.ToList();
```

I want to return `List<AccountVM>`

There is an compilation error:

```
Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<vw_web_GetAccounts>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AccountVM>'
```

Without the if condition example: It works as expected

```
var query = db.vw_web_GetAccounts
            .Where(...)
            .Select(a => new AccountVM
            {
                Name = a.Name,
                ....
            });

            return query.ToList();
```

How do I make it work with if condition?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linq: adding conditions to the where clause conditionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10884651/linq-adding-conditions-to-the-where-clause-conditionally)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to cast in the 1st statement. Also in the code shown you are missing the assignments.

```
var query = db.vw_web_GetAccounts as IQueryable<vw_web_GetAccounts>;
if (some condition)
{
    query = query.Where(...);
}
else
{
    query = query.Where(...);
}

return query.Select(a =>  new AccountVM
{
    Name = a.Name,
    ....
}).ToList();
```

Comment: yea. Where doesn't change the state, just returns it. i think that would work too. just be carefully because each where is a filter. so you're always making Where in a query that was already filtered.

Comment: When I modify the first line I still get the same compilation error. Anything else missing?

Comment: @Ben - See also the return statement I posted. There is no attempt to reassign the result from `query.Select(...` to `query`.

Comment: @Ben - also make sure the generic type constraints are correct, I guessed based on your error message.

Comment: Igor, I made an update, error is gone, but now it  seems the where condition is not picking up, it goes into the if condition but the result when I view contains all records.

Comment: @Ben - Make sure you are assigning the result of the `Where`. `query = query.Where(expression);`

Comment: Thank you very much!!! Works as expected. For my understanding can you please explain why we need to do cast (1 st line) and when? because if i put all into one condition without doing the if condition I  dont need to do the cast.

Comment: @Ben - `db.vw_web_GetAccounts` is of type `DbSet<T>` and `Where<T>()` returns type `IQueryable<T>`. You can't assign `IQueryable<T>` to `DbSet<T>` but the inverse is true as `DbSet<T>` implements `IQueryable<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

Error you are getting have nothing to do with the `if` condition, but the problem is that method return type is `List<AccountVM>` but the return value is of type `DbSet<vw_web_GetAccounts>`

One line solution would be the `ternary operator`, include condition in the `Where` clause and rest would be the same as you did in the without `if` condition version:

```
var query = db.vw_web_GetAccounts.Where(a => condition ? (...) : (...)).Select(a =>  
            new AccountVM
            {
              Name = a.Name,
              ....
            });

return query.ToList();
```