# EntityFramework Core nullable predicate ToListAsync

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, predicate

How do i use a nullable predicate to get the ToListAsync extension in EFCore.

```cs
Func<User, bool>? predicate = x => x.IsActive;

var result = await _context
  .User
  .Where(predicate)
  .ToListAsync();  // This extension is not available in this case

var anotherResult = await _context
  .User
  .Where(x => x.IsActive)
  .ToListAsync();  // Extension is available
```

I need the predicate to be nullable as it's going to be a optional parameter for the method. Is there a way to handle the nullable predicate in `Where`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linq: adding conditions to the where clause conditionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10884651/linq-adding-conditions-to-the-where-clause-conditionally)

Comment: @madreflection I could not find any in this link.

Comment: First of all, you need an actual entity set (table), not just `_context`, but `_context.SomeTable`, and assign that to an `IQueryable<SomeTable> query`.  Then, `if (predicate is not null) query = query.Where(predicate);`. Finally, `return await query.ToListAsync();`. The linked answer has booleans like `useAge` but the "not null" state of `predicate` is the boolean you need to use.

Comment: `Expression<Func<User, bool>>?` - it should fix compiler issue and prevent loading whole table.

Comment: @madreflection edited the question to add the missing table. Your suggestion with where is fine but i needed the ToListAsync. Refer Svyatoslav Danyliv for the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Where is the Expression delegate it wants from you. If you give the code below it will work

```
Expression<Func<User, bool>> predicate = x => x.IsActive;
```

Comment: Any reason to go with `Expression<Func<User, bool>?>` instead of `Expression<Func<User, bool>>?`

Comment: @prvn No, there's no reason at all (and I don't understand why you accepted this answer). It doesn't solve the compiler issue as you must have noticed. The method argument must be `Expression<Func<User, bool>>?` and inside the method you must deal with a null value, as you can't use `Where` with a null predicate.

Comment: @prvn actually your code is stuck there because i did copy paste null check no need